# Setting variables based on value taken from CSV within a Foreach loop using an if else statement

Tags: powershell

I've created a script that takes new user data from a CSV file and connects to AzureAd and ExchangeOnline to create their AzureAD account, assigns them an Office license (not shown), and updates their Mailbox `Office` field.

CSV headers are Name, Department, OfficeLocation. The CSV used to contain a Domain and Company header. I removed those headers and added an `if` `elseif` statement to provide the logic to set those variables within the script. Prior to this addition, the script worked without any issues.

Now, the `$company` and `$domain` values are only updating for `$main_offices` and `$corporate_offices` Contoso and @contoso.com even when the OfficeLocation value is San Francisco or Austin and those values should be West/South Acme and west/south.acme.com.

Why are my `$company` and `$domain` values not being updated within the `ForEach-Object` loop as it iterates through the CSV? I confirmed that `$company` and `$domain` update properly when not reading in CSV data with `ForEach-Object`:

```
$new_users = Import-Csv -Path .\new-users.csv

...

$main_offices = 'New York','Los Angeles','Houston','Atlanta','Chicago'
$corporate_offices = 'Corporate Office (NY)','Corporate Office (LA)'
$west_office = 'San Francisco'
$south_office = 'Austin'

$new_users | ForEach-Object {
    $first, $last = $_.Name.Split()
    $mailnickname = $(($first.Substring(0,1) + $last).ToLower())
    $password_profile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
    $password_profile.Password = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    $password_profile.ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = $false
    $off_loc = $_.OfficeLocation

    if ($off_loc -in $main_offices -or $corporate_offices) {
        $company = 'Contoso'
        $domain = '@contoso.com'
    } elseif ($off_loc -eq $west_office) {
        $company = 'West Acme'
        $domain = '@west.acme.com'
    } elseif ($off_loc -eq $south_office) {
        $company = 'South Acme'
        $domain = '@south.acme.com'
    } else { $off_loc = Read-Host 'Type an office location' } #CSV OfficeLocation field either missing or has a spelling error

    $attr_new_user = @{
        AccountEnabled = $true
        CompanyName = $company
        Department = $_.Department
        DisplayName = $_.Name
        GivenName = $first
        MailNickname = $mailnickname
        PasswordProfile = $password_profile
        Surname = $last
        UsageLocation = 'US'
        UserPrincipalName = $mailnickname + $domain
    }
    try {
        Write-Host ('>> Creating account for ' + $attr_new_user.DisplayName) -ForegroundColor Yellow
        New-AzureADUser @attr_new_user | Out-Null
        $user_upn = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $attr_new_user.UserPrincipalName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName
        Write-Host ('>> ' + $user_upn + ' has been created') -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host ('>> Something went wrong') -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Warning $Error[0]
    }

...

    try {
        Write-Host ('>> Adding email alias: ' + $alternate_email + ' and office: ' + $off_loc + ' to ' + $user_upn) -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Set-Mailbox -Identity $user_upn -EmailAddresses @{ add = $alternate_email } -Office $off_loc
        Write-Host ('>> Email Alias: ' + $alternate_email + ' and office: ' + $off_loc + ' added to ' + $user_upn) -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host ('>> Something went wrong') -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Warning $Error[0]
    }
```

I've run the script and the `$off_loc` value is being inputted correctly in the `Office` field of the Mailbox settings. Which is why I am having trouble understanding how to get this information to create the user with the correct the `$company` and `$domain` fields.

Any insight into a solution to this issue is appreciated, thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: This condition `$off_loc -in $main_offices -or $corporate_offices` will always be `$true` because `$corporate_offices` is not `$null` or empty string. It should be `$off_loc -in $main_offices -or $off_loc -in $corporate_offices`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Santiago Squarzon:

> This condition $off_loc -in $main_offices -or $corporate_offices will
> always be $true because $corporate_offices is not $null or empty
> string. It should be $off_loc -in $main_offices -or $off_loc -in
> $corporate_offices

Confirmed this resolved the issue.